# The C++ compiler g++.exe is not able to compile a simple test program - Determining if the CXX compiler works failed

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services

I have been trying to integrate the AWS SDK for C++ into my Netbeans Project. I try to use the cmake command but it fails with the following errors.

Here is the text from running the command in the command prompt

```
    C:\Users\jense\Desktop\code libraries\aws-sdk-cpp-master\aws-sdk-cpp-master>"C:\Users\jense\Desktop\code libraries\cmake-3.8.2-win64-x64\cmake-3.8.2-win64-x64\bin\cmake" .
-- Could NOT find Git (missing:  GIT_EXECUTABLE)
-- TARGET_ARCH not specified; inferring host OS to be platform compilation target
-- Building AWS libraries as shared objects
-- Generating windows build config
-- Building project version: 1.1.10
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_ade23\fast"
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Users/jense/Desktop/code libraries/cmake-3.8.2-win64-x64/cmake-3.8.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:44 (message):
  The C++ compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe" is not able to compile a simple
  test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/Users/jense/Desktop/code libraries/aws-sdk-cpp-master/aws-sdk-cpp-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

  Run Build Command:"nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_ade23\fast"

  Generator: execution of make failed.  Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO"
  "cmTC_ade23\fast"

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:105 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/jense/Desktop/code libraries/aws-sdk-cpp-master/aws-sdk-cpp-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/jense/Desktop/code libraries/aws-sdk-cpp-master/aws-sdk-cpp-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Here is inside my CMakeError.txt

```
    Determining if the CXX compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/jense/Desktop/code libraries/aws-sdk-cpp-master/aws-sdk-cpp-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_a5997\fast"

Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_a5997\fast"
```

Inside my `CMakeOutput.txt`

```
The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/Users/jense/Desktop/code libraries/aws-sdk-cpp-master/aws-sdk-cpp-master/CMakeFiles/3.8.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
0
Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.exe"
```

It says that `g++` cannot compile a simple test program, however it seems to work fine on my other `c++` programs. Also, it instructs me to run `nmake` `/NOLOGO` `cmTC_a5997\fast`. I cannot find nmake installed on my computer, is this the problem? Or is that just another error happening from a chain of errors?

How do I fix this?

I am using Netbeans 8.2 not Visual Studio.

All the answers I have seen on SO don't seem to relate to my issue, they are visual studio related answers and or something fixing a problem that I don't have.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with `cmake . -G"Unix Makefiles"`?  IIRC "NMake Makefiles" or Visual Studio Solution is the default generator on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

NMake is the traditional make program in the Microsoft toolchain. Since you use MinGW you need *mingw32-make*, but CMake defaults to the MS toolchain generator on Windows. Call CMake with `-G "MinGW Makefiles"` to switch to the MinGW generator.

`-G "Unix Makefiles"`, like Miles Budnek suggested in the question’s comments, is the default generator for Unix-like targets. For example, it’s the default on Linux. However, it is *not* the same as MinGW and won’t work in your situation.

P.S. 1: Especially on Windows *make* has its problems with using all your CPU cores. You might want to have a look at [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/). It’s usually a drop-in replacement for *make*, can be activated with CMake’s `-G Ninja` and handles parallel builds a lot better.

P.S. 2 (unrelated to the question): Avoid spaces anywhere in your directory paths. Those are a prime source for trouble because you’ll have to quote such paths properly everywhere. That’s (a) suprisingly difficult to get right, (b) something you can easily forget entirely and (c) something all your 3rd-party dependencies’ build systems need to be capable of as well. Not using spaces is the simplest way to avoid all those potential pitfalls.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I tried using -G "MinGW Makefiles" but they were already being used. There must've been deeper problems in my edited CMakeCache.txt file because it worked when I reinstalled the entire sdk and tried again. Thanks anyway!